# Out of memory error when reading from socket in C?

Tags: c, http, out-of-memory

I had written some code for an HTTP server in C. It works OK with a small number of clients (within the 100-500ish range maybe), but when asked to face a large number of concurrent users, it runs out of memory. I'm wondering as to why this happens.

Here's the code that reads data from the client and then returns a response. The client and server socket are non-blocking by the way:

```
int handle_client(char *root, int c) {

    int size = sizeof(char) * BUFSIZ + 1, len = strlen(SEND_HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
    char *buffer = malloc(size), *data = NULL, not_found_error[200] = SEND_HTTP_NOT_FOUND, internal_error[200] = SEND_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    if (!buffer) {
        log_error(errno);
        return -1;
    }

    bzero(buffer, size);

    while (1) {
        if (read(c, buffer, size) <= 0) {
             if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
                 log_error(errno);
                 free(buffer);
                 if (c) close(c);
                 return -1;
             } else {
                 int not_found = 0;
                 data = parse_content(root, buffer, not_found);
                 if (!data) {
                      if (not_found) {
                          if (write(c, not_found_error, len) <= 0)
                               log_error(errno);
                      } else {
                          if (write(c, internal_error, len) <= 0)
                               log_error(errno);
                      }

                      free(buffer);
                      if (c) close(c);
                      return -1;
                  }
                  break;
              }
         }
    }

    if (write(c, data, strlen(data)) <= 0) {
         if (errno != EAGAIN && errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
              log_error(errno);
              close(c);
              free(data);
              free(buffer);
              return -1;
         }
     }

     close(c);
     free(data);
     free(buffer);

     return 0;
}
```

In order to test this code, I used `siege`:

`siege --file=try_me.txt -c 1000 -v`

`try_me.txt` 2 URLs which request an index page and a file called `test.txt`, by the way. After only a little while of bombarding it with 1000 concurrent users, this happens:

`siege` output:

```
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.14 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.14 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.14 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.14 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.14 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     158 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.13 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 200     0.14 secs:     225 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.14 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.14 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.14 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     1.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     1.12 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.12 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.13 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /
 HTTP/1.1 500     0.14 secs:      41 bytes ==> GET  /test.txt
```

My program's output:

```
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate  memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
 [ERROR] tcp_server.h:140 (function handle_client): Cannot allocate memory (error code: 12)
```

My 3 questions are:

1. What is not being allocated memory?
2. Why is it not being allocated memory?
3. How do I properly allocate memory to it?

Thanks for any help. Feel free to ask for clarification or information.

Comment: Why do you need to allocate `buffer` dynamically? Its size will never change (unless `BUFSIZ` is a macro that expands to a run-time modified variable).

Comment: Also, but more unrelated to your problem, if `read` returns `0` then you should not check `errno`, since that's not an actual error and the value of `errno` will be undefined.

Comment: More related to your problem, the code you show might be where the out-of-memory problem manifests, but if you have other dynamic allocations you should really look at them too. For example, how much memory do you allocate for each connected client? Do you free all of it when a client disconnects?

Comment: Good points. I'll take a look into that.

Comment: In regards to your 3rd suggestion, I use at the end of the code I show `close(c)` when to close the connection with a client. I don't dynamically allocate any memory for each client (I use the standard `c = accept(s, NULL, 0);` where `s` is the server socket).

Comment: `read(c, buffer, size)` reads *up to* `size` bytes.  By throwing away the return value, you have no idea how many bytes are actually read.

Comment: Why does that matter? I only need to check for when the buffer doesn't have anymore data available. At that point I can proceed to parse and send the client their data. If there is still data in the buffer (we haven't hit the error EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK), then we keep looping to read that data.

Comment: I'm not getting out of memory errors anymore, however, after some point, the server starts sending HTTP 500s. The weird thing is that there aren't any errors being reported by my program. `siege` ends up being killed after a while, too.

Comment: regarding: `int size = sizeof(char) * BUFSIZ + 1, len = strlen(SEND_HTTP_NOT_FOUND);`  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  The expression is just cluttering the code.  Suggest removing that expression.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*  2) honor the width of the printed page (usually 72 or 80 columns) by splitting statements at reasonable token separators and indenting the lines, other than the first line of the statement.

Comment: note: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not a `int`  Also, the returned value is the 'index' to the terminating NUL byte.   That is 1 short of being long enough to hold the full string.  Suggest increasing 'size' (or the call to `malloc()` by +1

Comment: regarding: `if (read(c, buffer, size) <= 0)`  this will NOT NECESSARILY have received the full packet from the sender. Suggest, when the returned value is less than expected, to be checking this detail and using a 'moving window' as needed to input the rest of the packet.

Comment: regarding: `char not_found_error[200] = SEND_HTTP_NOT_FOUND;
    char internal_error[200] = SEND_HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;`  suggest making those two variables into `char *` so only one instance of the string exists rather than the string existing for every user, as separate instances on the stack.

Comment: when the call to `read()` returns -1 or 0, why is the code then trying to parse the input buffer?  There is nothing in the buffer.

Comment: regarding; `data = parse_content(root, buffer, not_found);`  for the call to `parse_content()` to modify the variable `not_found`, that must be a pointer to the variable.  Suggest: `data = parse_content(root, buffer, &not_found);`

Comment: regarding; `if (c) close(c);`  Why test `c`?  it is always going to be the socket value for communication with the current client.  Otherwise, the previous call to `read()` would have failed

Comment: Why should `data = parse_content(root, buffer, not_found);` have the `not_found` variable be a pointer?

Comment: As others have mentioned, `read(c, buffer, size)` throwing away the size is bad, but it's because when you do, you overwrite the beginning of the buffer for every read, instead of appending to what's already read. That way, your buffer will contain garbage if more than one read() is needed.

Comment: I understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so I managed to pinpoint where the issue was occurring. Everyone's suggestions and comments helped me improve my code and also further helped fix the problem, so I thank you for that. 
The issue was in a line in another function that I wrote, in which I allocate an array that's `BUFSIZ` long! That's clearly not very memory efficient.

So, once again, I would like to thank you for your comments and suggestions!